# Streaming mp4a AAC SBR using JavaFX

Tags: java, audio, javafx-2, audio-streaming

I'm using JavaFX in a desktop application to create a media player to play both local mp3 files and url streamings. But I couldn't stream URL that was in mp4a AAC format.

This is a sample code:

```
public class WebRadioDemo extends Application {

    Media media;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            media = new Media (new URL("http://icecastsource2.amri.ca/cjab-mp3").toURI().toString());
                } catch (MalformedURLException | URISyntaxException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(WebRadioDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        Button btnMusica = new Button();
        btnMusica.setText("Tocar Música");
        btnMusica.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        btnMusica.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {

                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
                System.out.println("Tocar musica: "+media.getSource());
                System.out.println("aaaa: "+mediaPlayer.getMedia());
                mediaPlayer.play();

                mediaPlayer.setOnError(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.err.println(mediaPlayer.getError());
                    }
                });

            }
        });


        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        //   root.getChildren().add(btn);
        root.getChildren().add(btnMusica);


        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);      
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
    }

}
```

When I call the aac stream first, the player froze, and nothing responds, but when i call the aac stream after a local file play or a mp3 stream, it's give me a exception:

```
MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
```

This is the aac stream: it play normaly in media classic, itunes, etc:
`http://70.38.9.243:8402/stream`

This is the mp3 stream: `http://icecastsource2.amri.ca/cjab-mp3`

What is the best way to play the streamings that aren't in mp3 format?

Comment: Please translate the messages to English.

Comment: Ops, sorry. Its the same message, i just forgot to delete the other one. Thanks.

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: Firtly no, but i got a MediaException: Player cannot be created when de MediaPlayer object is not null when i tried the aac stream.

Comment: Please add the excpetion message and the stack trace to your question.

Comment: Done. That's the only exception message i got.

Comment: Can you post a SSCCE?

Comment: Also post the generated URIs, please.

Comment: Done. To play a local file, just change the new URL() to a new File() in the button event